# PowerShell: How to check for multiple conditions (folder existence)

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of writing a script to make changes to folder permissions. Before it does that I would to do some checking to make sure that I am working in the correct directory. My problem is how do I check to see if four subfolders (i.e. Admin, Workspace, Com, & Data) exists before the script progresses. I assume I would be using Test-Path on each directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What's wrong with the following?

```
if ( (Test-Path $path1) -and (Test-Path $path2) ) { 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Remember to specify `-LiteralPath` - stops any possible misinterpretation.  I've "been there" (so to speak) with this one, spending hours debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

Test-Path can check multiple paths at once. Like this:

```
Test-Path "c:\path1","c:\path2"
```

The output will be an array of True/False for each corresponding path.

This could be especially helpful if you have a lot of files/folders to check.

Check if all paths are exists:

```
if ((Test-Path $arraywithpaths) -notcontains $false) {...}
```

Same way for the non-existence:

```
if ((Test-Path $arraywithpaths) -contains $false) {...}
```